# Query in Spark SQL inside an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

To give the backfround I have loaded the JSON using

```
sqlContext.read.json(sn3://...)
df.registerTable("posts")
```

I have the following schema for my table in Spark

```
scala> posts.printSchema
root
 |-- command: string (nullable = true)
 |-- externalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceMap: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to select all posts with hashtag "nike"

```
sqlContext.sql("select sourceMap['hashtags'] as ht from posts where ht.contains('nike')");
```

I get an error 
undefined function ht.contains

I am not sure what method to use to search within the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer referring to Hive SQL.

```
sqlContext.sql("select sourceMap['hashtags'] from posts where array_contains(sourceMap['hashtags'], 'nike')");
```

The key function is array_contains()